# Ubuntu 14.04 Laptop: Mouse cursor not moving but mouse buttons work

Tags: mouse, touchpad

As the title states the mouse cursor on my laptop isn't moving but the mouse buttons still work. I'm not sure what to do. I have tested the touchpad on Windows and it works fine.

My laptop is a HP Envy

Xinput output `xinput list`

```
Virtual core pointer    id=2 [master pointer (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer    id =4 [slave pointer (2)]
SynPS/2 synaptics TouchPad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]
```

`uname -r`

3.16.0-49-generic

`lspci -K | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1966
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [Geoforce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard company device 219c
```

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` after driver install

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1966
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [Geoforce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard company device 219c
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

**Edit**

Turns out that a USB Mouse does work but I have yet to find out why my TrackPad stopped working.

Comment: What is your laptop model? Please give output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `uname -r`.

Comment: If your "Ubuntu 14" is 14.04, then upgrade the kernel by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` command. Then reboot and test. There are a few fixes in 3.19 for synaptics.

Comment: @Pilot6 unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu version? Is it 14.10 or 14.04?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try to run `sudo prime-select intel` and reboot.

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid

Comment: Does `uname -r` show 3.19?

Comment: It shows 3.19.0-28-generic

Comment: I have no more ideas. You can try newer kernels from mainline ppa. Please do not ask me how to do it, but search it in AU or google. That may help or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do with a configuration issue related to "disable touchpad while typing" although I haven't found a solution yet either.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue on both my laptops with Xubuntu 16.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update software... I had this problem, and all I know about it is that it is related to the default PS/2 driver on 14.04 (it don't support SynPS/2 -I have the same touchpad-). You can confirm it by using an USB external mouse: it will work.

Then, go to terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Enter your password, wait for updates. Reboot... if your Synaptics touchpad still don't work, then:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Enter your password, wait for updates... with this packages you will get also some extras like Microsoft fonts. So you will see a license agreement on terminal... use the 'TAB' button on keyboard to select the 'Ok' option and press Enter.

Once your system is updated, reboot... your touchpad should work after it.

Abraham Medina

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Did you ever get it working ?  Is it an ALPS compatable pad ?, Do you have a pointing cap as well ?  Beware that this could be disabled in bios (I do this on lenovos).  Did it *ever* work ?  Did you get it to work with a live distro ?